# Subject never emit (next never excute) how to catch the error

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subject

```js
zip(this.selectedProviderId, this.paymentMethodId).pipe(
    switchMap(response => this.ticketsService.getProviderAndPayerCredential(response[0], response[1]))
).subscribe(
    response => {
        response.forEach(item => { 
            if (item.PortalName === "Ams Portal") { 
                this.providerCredential.PortalName = item.PortalAms;
                this.providerCredential.UserId     = item.UserId;
                this.providerCredential.Password   = item.Password;
                this.providerCredential.Link       = item.BaseUrl;
            } else { 
                this.payerCredential.PortalName = item.PayerName;
                this.payerCredential.UserId     = item.UserId;
                this.payerCredential.Password   = item.Password;
                this.payerCredential.Link       = item.BaseUrl;
            } 
        }) 
        this.portalCredentialLoading = false;
    }, 
    _error => { 
        this.portalCredentialLoading = false; 
    }
);

selectedProviderId: Subject = new Subject(); 
paymentMethodId: Subject = new Subject();

this.ticketsService.getTicketDetails(id, 'Provider').subscribe(
    data => { 
        this.selectedProviderId.next(data.Id); 
    }
);
```

the subscribe above never happen , then selectedProviderId never emit

Comment: Are you saying that `this.ticketsService.getTicketDetails` never emits?  Please share the code for this method.

Comment: First, please post a comprehensive code snipet., the code you posted dosen't make sense. Second, when using ZIP function you only get the NEXT triggered when all the observables emit. Make sure that they are really emmiting a value.